# How to subset data in R?

Tags: r, object, subset

We have this question in our R lab. I wrote heartFailure=hospital["MORT_30_HF","Measure.ID"] for part b, I am not sure if it's right though. Then, I tried part c) over and over and still didn't understand how to approach anyways.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbhEQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
heartFailure <- hospital[ ,c("MORT_30_HF","Measure.ID")]
```

OR

```
heartFailure <- hospital[c("MORT_30_HF","Measure.ID")]
```